# Postgresql Long Startup time during queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have run two queries on the two different RDS boxes (one is the snapshot of the other). However, they have wildly different execution times:

```
  Aggregate  (cost=444569.62..444569.63 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=522034.540..522034.540 rows=1 loops=1)
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..444562.65 rows=2787 width=0) (actual time=0.081..522034.467 rows=77 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan using order_ordered_time_1e40c434713a9365_uniq on order o  (cost=0.56..17745.81 rows=53151 width=4) (actual time=0.033..396257.628 rows=841931 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (ordered_time > '2017-07-05 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                 Filter: ((payment_txn_status)::text = 'success'::text)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 114265
           ->  Index Scan using orderstatus_pkey on orderstatus s  (cost=0.56..8.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.148..0.148 rows=0 loops=841931)
                 Index Cond: (id = o.status_id)
                 Filter: ((order_status)::text = 'ordered'::text)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Total runtime: 522034.656 ms
  (11 rows)



  Aggregate  (cost=444569.62..444569.63 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=4281.653..4281.653 rows=1 loops=1)
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..444562.65 rows=2787 width=0) (actual time=0.173..4281.623 rows=77 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan using order_ordered_time_1e40c434713a9365_uniq on order o  (cost=0.56..17745.81 rows=53151 width=4) (actual time=0.076..1768.079 rows=841931 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (ordered_time > '2017-07-05 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                 Filter: ((payment_txn_status)::text = 'success'::text)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 114265
           ->  Index Scan using orderstatus_pkey on orderstatus s  (cost=0.56..8.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=841931)
                 Index Cond: (id = o.status_id)
                 Filter: ((order_status)::text = 'ordered'::text)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Total runtime: 4281.759 ms
  (11 rows)
```

You can see the first one took 52 seconds, and the second one only 4 seconds.

The difference is in the Actual times. In the first one

```
(actual time=0.033..396257.628 rows=841931 loops=1)
(actual time=0.148..0.148 rows=0 loops=841931)
```

And in the second one:

```
(actual time=0.076..1768.079 rows=841931 loops=1)
(actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=841931)
```

Its not that the first one was under load, it had only 1 or 2 connections.

What could cause such a large difference?

EDIT:

Adding the output of running Explain with COSTS, VERBOSE, TIMING, ANALYZE, BUFFERS

```
  Aggregate  (cost=1864809.48..1864809.49 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=59049.685..59049.685 rows=1 loops=1)
     Output: count(*)
     Buffers: shared hit=5660008 read=1110637
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=100813.94..1864770.09 rows=15755 width=0) (actual time=44066.839..59049.570 rows=211 loops=1)
           Hash Cond: (  orderstatus.id =   o.status_id)
           Buffers: shared hit=5660008 read=1110637
           ->  Seq Scan on public.  orderstatus  (cost=0.00..1728000.45 rows=2603502 width=4) (actual time=0.073..8608.230 rows=2679901 loops=1)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 19017896
                 Buffers: shared hit=350100 read=1110637
           ->  Hash  (cost=97058.54..97058.54 rows=300432 width=4) (actual time=7609.004..7609.004 rows=4629931 loops=1)
                 Output:   o.status_id
                 Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 162772kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=5309908
                 ->  Index Scan using   order_ordered_time_1e40c434713a9365_uniq on public.  order  (cost=0.56..97058.54 rows=300432 width=4) (actual time=0.031..6157.809 rows=4629931 loops=1)
                       Output:   o.status_id
                       Index Cond: (  o.ordered_time > '2017-06-03 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                       Filter: ((  o.payment_txn_status)::text = 'success'::text)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 625854
                       Buffers: shared hit=5309908
   Total runtime: 59073.565 ms
  (22 rows)
```

Comment: Do both severs have the same `postgresql.conf `?  Could you please show `explain (analyse on, costs of, buffers)` ?

Comment: you might also want to include `timing` in the analyze options to see the I/O timings in the plan

Comment: And, adding the @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, `BUFFERS`, too.  Like `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING) SELECT ...`  Are the instances the same type, BTW?

Comment: Consider [merging your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Who were you, @DG428? WHAT DID YOU SEE?!